# Convert Netgear DGN1000v3 (modem + router) as router only

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wan

Until recently my ISP gave me a DSL as input, now I changed my ISP. My new ISP gives me RJ-45 as input. After reading some pages about how to make my modem+router as a router only I "disabled the DHCP server" option. After doing this I ran into two set of problems

1. I can connect only one device at a time. (I have my PC hardwired to the Modem if I connect a mobile device via Wi-Fi it disconnects the PC and then connects the mobile into the network)
2. I cannot login to my router home page (The default gateway returns no connection found, www.routerlogin.net says that "You are not connected to your Router’s WiFi network.". Netgear genie doesn't login at all)

How can I solve these problems?

Comment: Keep the DHCP server as it affects your internal network only and since the device is the router you need DHCP for any devices with "automatic settings" connecting to the said router to have an assigned IP address. Otherwise you'd need to configure each one with (different) static IPs. The setup you want may not be possible. Generally speaking, if it hasn't a RJ45 WAN port it can't be done (with the original firmware).

Comment: By changing the firmware can I make it work as a router? If so please suggest me a firmware and a tutorial on how to do it. @MichaelBay

Comment: It works as a router already. The question was about having a dedicated WAN port or not (Not). That said, according to the manual it can work with sources other than its internal xDSL modem and you can use the "genie" to set it up (it should detect which port is now the WAN port and which ones are for LAN clients). Of course, alternative firmwares like DD-WRT, OpenWRT or Tomato allow for much finer tunning but that doesn't mean you can't do with the original firmwares but using two routers in cascade can be tricky when you don't know enough about networking (you really don't).

Comment: I disconnected the DSL wire and connected the RJ - 45 in all the 4 ports and ran the auto setup wizard and it said "internet not detected" all the time. Guess I have to install the custom firmware. @MichaelBay